# Unable to compile C# within TestDome case setup

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a custom test in TestDome and it starts with C#. While TestDome allows for multiple tests, I would be happy with one test, is there a distinct list of names and months?

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;

// Class should be named {QuestionName} + Test and should derive from TestBase
// White spaces, minuses, commas and dots in {QuestionName} are ignored
public class TransactionsbymonthTest : TestBase
{
    // A candidate's solution is provided through property:
    //   string Solution
    
    // Database connection is provided through property:
    //   DbConnection DbConnection

    // Currently evaluating sql engine is provided through property:
    //   SqlEngine SqlEngine
    // SqlEngine is an enum with values [MsSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite]
    
    // A helper method to execute non query:
    //   DbCommand ExecuteNonQuery(string sqlString)
    
    // A helper method to execute reader:
    //   DbDataReader ExecuteReader(string sqlString)
    
    // A helper  method for writing the content of the DataTable to the tab 'Output':
    //   void DisplayDataTable(DataTable dt)
    
    // A helper method for writing the content of the DataTable after executing provided SQL:
    //   void DisplayDataTable(string sqlString)
   
    // Test case methods should be named test1, test2, test3...
    [Test, Description("Transactions by month")]
    public void test1()
    {
        var createTable =
// Create the customers table
ExecuteNonQuery(@"CREATE TABLE customers 
                ( 
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
                )");

// Insert data into the customers table
ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO customers(id, name) values(1, 'Joseph')");
ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO customers(id, name) values(2, 'Radha')");
ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO customers(id, name) values(3, 'Rebecca')");

// Create the transactions table
ExecuteNonQuery(@"CREATE TABLE transactions 
                ( 
                    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                    amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    transaction_date DATE NOT NULL,
                    customerID INTEGER NOT NULL,
                    FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES customers(id)
                )");

// Insert data into the transactions table
ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO transactions(id, amount, transaction_date, customerID) values(1, 150, '2022/06/17', 1)");
ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO transactions(id, amount, transaction_date, customerID) values(2, 275, '2023/08/23', 1)");
ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO transactions(id, amount, transaction_date, customerID) values(3, 450, '2023/08/25', 1)");
ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO transactions(id, amount, transaction_date, customerID) values(4, 75, '2023/01/01', 2)");
ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO transactions(id, amount, transaction_date, customerID) values(5, 125, '2023/07/04', 2)");
ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO transactions(id, amount, transaction_date, customerID) values(6, 25, '2023/04/08', 3)");

    // Retrieve data from the transactions table
    var reader = ExecuteReader(@"
        SELECT 
          a.name,
          DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, transaction_date), 0) AS month,
          SUM(amount) AS amount 
        FROM customers a
        LEFT JOIN transactions b ON a.id = b.customerID
        GROUP BY a.name, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, transaction_date), 0)
        ORDER BY month, amount DESC;
    ");

    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);

    // Assertions for the transactions table
    Assert.AreEqual(6, dt.Rows.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, dt.Columns.Count);

    Assert.AreEqual("Joseph", dt.Rows[0][0]);
    Assert.AreEqual("Joseph", dt.Rows[1][0]);
    Assert.AreEqual("Radha", dt.Rows[2][0]);
    Assert.AreEqual("Radha", dt.Rows[3][0]);
    Assert.AreEqual("Rebecca", dt.Rows[4][0]);      
      

    
    }
    
    // The output of the method Main is written to the tab 'Output' on the candidate's screen.
    // This test case is not included in the candidate's score. 
    [Test]
    public void Main()
    {
        var createTable =
                @"CREATE TABLE output 
                ( 
                    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                    transaction_month DATE NOT NULL,
                    amount INTEGER
                )";
        ExecuteNonQuery(createTable);
        ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO output(name, transaction_month, amount) values('Joseph','2022/06/01',150)");
        ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO output(name, transaction_month, amount) values('Joseph','2023/08/01',725)"); 
        ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO output(name, transaction_month, amount) values('Radha','2023/01/01',75)");    
        ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO output(name, transaction_month, amount) values('Radha','2023/07/01',125)");       
        ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO output(name, transaction_month, amount) values('Rebecca','2023/04/01',25)"); 
        
        DisplayDataTable(base.Solution);
    }
}
```

Here is the accompanying prompt:

> A company has been monitoring transactions for customers over the years. The data is stored in the following tables:

```
TABLE customers
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL

TABLE transactions
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  amount INTEGER NOT NULL
  transaction_date DATE NOT NULL
  customerID INTEGER
  FOREIGN KEY (customerID) REFERENCES customers(id)
```

> Write a query that returns:

> Customer names
> Sum of their contributions by month

And the expected SQL solution

```
SELECT 
  a.name,
  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, transaction_date), 0) AS month,
  SUM(amount) AS amount 
FROM customers a
LEFT JOIN transactions b ON a.id = b.customerID
GROUP BY a.name, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, transaction_date), 0)
ORDER BY month, amount DESC;
```

Right now, using SQL Server as the only permissible test SQL language I am getting this error

> Transactions by month: Wrong answer

Comment: Your question is about "sum of their contributions by month BY YEAR" - where do you believe the year is being accounted for in your current query?  And what do you specifically believe is being achieved by ... DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, transaction_date), 0) ... to me that appears to be a superfluous use of functions that doesn't actually get you any closer to identifying the specific "month" value than if you just used "transaction_date" alone.  Why make SQL do unnecessary work?

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for your review. From a financial perspective we often look at transactional data at a monthly level so that we can align the transactions to the monthly accounting close process. The DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, transaction_date), 0) AS month, is intended to get to the beginning of month and group transactionid 2 and transactionid 3 into a single row (2023/08/01). I've removed the reference to year in the prompt for clarity.

Comment: So have you read through the `Assert`s for `Transactions by month`? What do you notice about the customer names and row numbers? If you execute your T-SQL code in SSMS what do you see?

Comment: Thanks, AlwaysLearning. I only have a very basic understanding of what the Asserts do. I am expecting five rows to be returned from the expected SQL solution and so my expectation is that the Assert will test whether each of those five rows matches the values {Joseph;Joseph;Radha;Radha;Rebecca}.